# mySql query to find the maximum 3 values from a column and group by on other column

Tags: mysql, sql

Table student

```
Name Class Marks
abc    a    95
zxc    a    90
ert    a    85
hjk    a    80
iur    b    98
iue    b    96
opi    b    94
ool    b    90
```

Output

```
Name Class Marks
abc    a    95
zxc    a    90
ert    a    85
iur    b    98
iue    b    96
opi    b    94
```

Here we have to group on column class and get the maximum three values for column Marks. There could be different values for column class like c,d,e,f,g etc.

Comment: Emulate `row_number() Over()` as shown in the tutorial http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Comment: unable to apply the concept of row_number() in this context.

Comment: Concept : `select  * from ( select *, row_number() over(partition by Class order by Marks desc) as rn from student) tt where rn<=3`

Comment: Row_number() not working in mysql. The above query throws syntax error.

Comment: Exactly. This is why you need to emulate it as in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use variables:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = class, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := class, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from student s cross join
           (select @c := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by class, marks desc
     ) s
where seqnum <= 3;
```